# RInside Compilation: Make Targets

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rinside

I am new to using make and I am trying to run the RInside example for Qt density demo given here: http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/03/25/. I have saved the code into the following files:

main.cpp
Makefile
qtdensity.cpp
include/qtdensity.h

I am running Ubuntu 13.10, I have R, Rcpp and Inside installed. When I go to the terminal and run

```
> make -f Makefile
```

I get the error

```
make: *** No targets. Stop.
```

Please let me know how to proceed.

Thank you

---

I can't see how to ask a follow up to the first answer so I have to extend my question:

I have just created the files and was able to run qmake on main.cpp, qtdensity.cpp, qtdensity.h, and qtdensity.pro which worked but when I tried to run make, I get the following errors:

Lots of R - related errors ...

```
qtdensity.cpp:(.text+0x53a): undefined reference to `Rf_mkString'
qtdensity.cpp:(.text+0x54e): undefined reference to `Rf_install'
qtdensity.cpp:(.text+0x559): undefined reference to `Rf_findVarInFrame'
qtdensity.cpp:(.text+0x560): undefined reference to `R_UnboundValue'
...

qtdensity.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2a5): undefined reference to `R_NaReal'
qtdensity.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2b2): undefined reference to `R_NaN'
main.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2a5): undefined reference to `R_NaReal'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2b2): undefined reference to `R_NaN'
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x352): undefined reference to `RInside::RInside(int, char const* const*, bool, bool, bool)'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x397): undefined reference to `RInside::~RInside()'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3b3): undefined reference to `RInside::~RInside()'
moc_qtdensity.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN9QtDensity18qt_static_metacallEP7QObjectN11QMetaObject4CallEiPPv':
moc_qtdensity.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2a5): undefined reference to `R_NaReal'
moc_qtdensity.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2b2): undefined reference to `R_NaN'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [qdensity] Error 1
```

Comment: It didn't link with R or RInside. Maybe your system is non-standard. As I showed you -- works here.

Answer (score 0):

The Qt example is different because it uses Qt. You *always* need to start by creating the Makefile itself from the .pro file.  Witness:

```
edd@max:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/qt$ ls -l        ## no Makefile
total 28
drwxrwxr-x 2 edd edd 4096 Dec 27 18:38 cmake
-rw-rw-r-- 1 edd edd  518 Dec 27 18:38 main.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 edd edd 5953 Dec 27 18:38 qtdensity.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 edd edd 1532 Dec 27 18:38 qtdensity.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 edd edd 2378 Feb 11 20:14 qtdensity.pro
-rw-rw-r-- 1 edd edd  887 Dec 27 18:38 README
edd@max:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/qt$ qmake        ## creates Makefile
edd@max:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/qt$ make
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -I/usr/share/R/include [... lots and lots omitted ...]
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o qtdensity qtdensity.o main.o moc_qtdensity.o  [....]
edd@max:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/qt$ ls -l qtdensity
-rwxrwxr-x 1 edd edd 76666 Feb 14 15:02 qtdensity
edd@max:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/qt$
```

This **is** of course also described in the README in this directory...